# VBA, loop directory, file causing error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that loops through directory, but when it reaches a certain file, I get a run time error 13. Type mismatch.

debug line:

```
measurement = ws.Evaluate("sumproduct((" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(lrw, i)).Address & "<>"""")+0)") / (lrw - 1)
```

All the other files in my directory work fine, just this one. contains 3 sheets. Any ideas? I can open the file fine. The code actually works halfway through the workbook and stops in sheet 2.

```
Sub stackmeup()
'added function to skip corrupt files works! Adding skipped files works.. and do something about 50%.
'changed lrw to long, doesnt skip those files now :)



Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean 'part of loop


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim resultSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lco As Integer
Dim lrw As Long
Dim resultRow As Integer
Dim measurement As Double

'To compile skipped files
Dim wksSkipped As Worksheet
Set wksSkipped = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skipped")


Set resultSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
resultRow = 1

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'get user input for files to search
  Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
  If errCheck Then Exit Sub


For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Cells(wksSkipped.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = fileNames(Key)
Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible


    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells) = 0 Then
            'define the range to measure
            lco = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious, False).Column
            lrw = ws.Columns("A:Y").Find("*", , xlValues, , xlRows, xlPrevious).Row
            If lrw = 1 Then lrw = 2
            For i = 1 To lco
                measurement = ws.Evaluate("sumproduct((" & ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(lrw, i)).Address & "<>"""")+0)") / (lrw - 1)
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 1).Value = wb.Name
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 2).Value = ws.Name
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 3).Value = ws.Cells(1, i).Value
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 4).Style = "Percent"
                resultSheet.Cells(resultRow, 5).Value = measurement
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
    wb.Application.Visible = True '' I added
    wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
    Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
    End If
Next 'End of the fileNames loop

Set fileNames = Nothing
'Message Box when tasks are completed
MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: For some reason, moving up the on `error resume next` worked, hm I wonder why.

Comment: I have a feeling the range it is trying to sumproduct is not an actual number.

Comment: On error resume next just means if it encounters an error it just skips the line.  Be careful, it can give the false sense that code is working when really it is just skipping all the errors it comes across.

Comment: @Yaegz, your right. Well the page it gets stuck on actually is blank aside from headers. but maybe a hidden value or something? I have no idea.

Comment: Do the other files have data on that particular sheet?

Comment: Yes , but its quite random, some may, some may not. I dont think it is to do with it being blank as I have some others that work when blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for sheets which give an error using something like this:

```
Dim measurement As Variant
'...
'...

For i = 1 To lco

    On Error Resume Next
    measurement = ws.Evaluate("sumproduct((" & _
               ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(lrw, i)).Address & _
               "<>"""")+0)") / (lrw - 1)
    On Error Goto 0

    With resultSheet.Rows(resultRow)
        .Cells(1).Value = wb.Name
        .Cells(2).Value = ws.Name
        .Cells(3).Value = ws.Cells(1, i).Value
        .Cells(4).Style = "Percent"
        .Cells(5).Value = IIf(IsError(measurement),"Error!",measurement)
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, what could I do (with the If not part)? Put file into sheet specifying that it was skipped?

Comment: Thanks tim, will test and let you know results, what will this change from my current results?

Comment: The only thing that should change is you see "Error!" for lines where the `Evaluate` produced an error instead of a result.

Comment: Thanks tim, it works. When I skip the error for some reason, the workbook seems to populate results and not give and "error"